# React not able to Reuse custom component twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have created a custom component to upload image with Filereader given below:

```
import { Alert, Box, Snackbar, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { ReactElement, useState } from "react";

const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
const allowdImageTypes: string[] = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"];

const DropZone = ({
  title,
  imagesHandler,
}: {
  title: string;
  imagesHandler: Function;
}): ReactElement => {
  const [error, setError] = useState<null | string>(null);
  const [previewFile, setPreviewFile] = useState<any>(null);

  const photoHandler = (event: { target: { files: any } }) => {
    imagesHandler({ [title]: "" });
    const temp: Blob | undefined = event?.target!.files[0];

    if (temp) {
      if (!allowdImageTypes.includes(temp.type)) {
        setError("File does not support. You must use .png or .jpg ");
        return;
      }
      // 1 MB max
      if (temp.size > 10e5) {
        setError("Please upload a file smaller than 1 MB");
        return;
      }
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        // console.log({ [title]: temp });
        imagesHandler({ [title]: temp });
        setPreviewFile(e.target?.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(temp);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <Stack mt={2} width={1}>
        <input
          accept=".png, .jpg, /.jpeg"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          id="raised-button-file"
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => photoHandler(e)}
        />
        <label
          htmlFor="raised-button-file"
          style={{
            cursor: "pointer",
            textAlign: "center",
            borderColor: "#ccc",
            padding: "1rem",
            border: "1px dashed",
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}
        >
          <Typography
            variant="subtitle2"
            color="info.main"
            display="flex"
            justifyContent="center"
            alignItems="center"
          >
            Click to upload {title ? title.toString().toLowerCase() : "photo"}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="caption" noWrap color="info.main">
            Size &lt;= 1MB
          </Typography>
        </label>
      </Stack>
      {previewFile && (
        <Box>
          <img
            src={previewFile}
            style={{ maxHeight: 150, width: "100%" }}
            alt="thumbnail"
          />
        </Box>
      )}
      {error && (
        <Snackbar
          open={error ? true : false}
          autoHideDuration={3000}
          onClose={() => setError(null)}
        >
          <Alert elevation={6} variant="filled" severity="error">
            {error}
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default DropZone;
```

And I am calling it in another component like this:

```
import DropZone from "./DropZone";

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState<{
    thumb: any;
    header: any;
  }>({
    thumb: "",
    header: "",
  });
  const imageHandler = (imgData: { header?: any; thumb?: any }) => {
    console.log(imgData);
    setInput({ ...input, ...imgData });
  };
 return (
    <>
      <DropZone key={1} title="thumb" imagesHandler={imageHandler} />
      <DropZone key={2} title="header" imagesHandler={imageHandler} />
    </>
  )

  export default ImageUpload;
}
```

Its working fine and rendering two fields of Dropzone image upload.

**When I click on first dropZone for thumb and upload image, it works fine but for second dropZone it's returning value for thumb prop only not for Header prop. no matter how many times I call DropZone it always take first instance. Can someone please help me to get the separate instance for each DropZone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is that both of your DropZone components use the same id for the input. Because an element's id must be unique within the document, the `<label>` for "header" ends up targeting the `<input>` for "thumb", because it's first in the document.

```
<input
  id="raised-button-file" // <==== both file inputs have the same id
  ...
/>

<label
  htmlFor="raised-button-file" // <=== both labels target the first input
  ...
>
```

Try giving them distinct ids:

```
// incorporate the title to make a distinct id 
const inputId = `raised-button-file-${title}`; // or whatever

<input
  id={inputId} // <=== title-specific id
  ...
/>

<label
  htmlFor={inputId}  // <=== title-specific id
  ...
>
```

Comment: You are a true saviour. It completely worked. Thanks a ton